# SCCM Detection Methods - where are they stored?

Tags: package, detection, agent, sccm

By the end of last week our central IT Department introduced SCCM and applied it to a bunch of clients in our division. My colleagues and I work as so called "IT-Partner" in a 1st level support for a few hundrets of colleagues. Now we're facing some problems with our new SCCM System (installed packages do not work etc.) Now we'd like to "reset" applications so the SCCM Agend will reinstall them. I've read something about the detection methods but unfortunatelly I do not really know how they work nor I know where those methods are saved. I want to "analyse" those methods so I know which file to modify / delete that the agent will reinstall the application.

By the way, how much time does SCCM take from "assigning" a package to applying to the client?

Comment: I think you need someone experienced with application deployment and SCCM to help with this.  Getting applications to deploy reliably using SCCM is an involved, complicated thing to achieve that takes months of learning and testing to get right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only have the client and no access to the SCCM Console the detection methods can be found using WMI. They are stored in root\ccm\CIModels in the Class Local_Detect_Synclet.

The format is XML in one column and it is designed so that all kinds of detection methods can basically be represented in the same style so it's not very readable but you should be able to get some basic understanding about the detection method used.

Keep in mind this is only true if the software was deployed in the "new" (introduced in sccm 2012) application format and not for the "old" package/program format.

If you want more detail I once tried to automate the process of triggering a reinstall for any given application but ultimately failed due to problems with the chache/distribution point. I posted all my findings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950457/is-there-a-way-to-reinstall-an-application-in-sccm-2012/29006705#29006705).

Answer (score 0):

So from an application POV. When you deploy an app the detection method is setup in SCCM to determine wether or not the application installed successfully. This detection method could be configured a variety of ways. For example, it could check to see if the msi code is installed to determine success, it could check the .exe and compare it to a specific version, or even check a registry file for existence. In order to change/modify these detection methods you should be an SCCM admin and be able to login to the console. From there you would select the specific application or package you want to analyze and click through the properties of the deployment.