# Invoke-cimMethod ccm_application DownloadContents

Tags: powershell, sccm

These are the arguments I created in the Hash `$arguments1`

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $arguments1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Priority                       Low
Revision                       69
IsMachineTarget                True
Id                             ScopeId_68206A1F-8356-4C20-B224-D3FC15535521/Application_8426614e-0098-416c-99c1-65ac92c0ee21
```

This is the command I used:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName ccm_application -Namespace root\ccm\clientSDK -Name DownloadContents -Arguments $arguments1
```

This is the error I got in response:

> Invoke-CimMethod : A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.
>       At line:1 char:1
>       + Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName ccm_application -Namespace root\ccm\clien ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root\ccm\clientSDK:ccm_application:String) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800706f4,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand

Comment: Should it not be `-methodname` instead of `-name`?

Comment: with -methodname:
..... -MethodName DownloadContents ...



Is the same error:
Invoke-CimMethod : A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName ccm_application -Namespace root\ccm\clien ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root\ccm\clientSDK:ccm_application:String) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800706f4,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand

Comment: It's been a while (so different sccm version) and I have not investigated further but last time I looked into this was in the answer (and comments) of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950457/is-there-a-way-to-reinstall-an-application-in-sccm-2012/29006705 at this point it just seemed like the downloadcontents method was broken as it never behaved as expected. I am no where near an expert on this and it might have changed in the mean time so take this info with a grain of salt